# Why doesn't QTextBrowser::clear() work immediately when i call it?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I want achieve a function : when I clickt the "start" button,the textBrowser will be cleaned up immediately and then the textBrowser show something for user.But I use `QtextBrowser::clear()` ,it didn't work immediately.

```
//constructor
connect(StartBtn,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(interfaceStart()));

bool MainWindow::interfaceStart()
{
    ui->textBrowser->clear();// this line does not seem to work immediately before `while(fgets...)` loop is finished;
    if(interfaceLine->text()!=QString("") && interfaceSpinBox->text()!="0"){
        ui->textBrowser->insertPlainText(QString("Starting capture interface %1 \n\n").arg(interfaceLine->text()));//this line also doesn't work
        std::string  cc = std::string("tshark -i ")
                +std::string((interfaceLine->text()).toLocal8Bit().data())
                +std::string(" -a duration:")
                +std::string(interfaceSpinBox->text().toLocal8Bit().data());
        char buf[1024];
        char const *command=cc.c_str();
        std::cout<<command;
        std::cout.flush(); // when i see this line work, console will output command.But textBroser is't cleaned up
        FILE *ptr;

        if((ptr=popen(command, "r"))!=NULL)
        {
            while(fgets(buf, 1024, ptr)!=NULL)
            {
                ui->textBrowser->insertPlainText(buf);
            }
            pclose(ptr);
            ptr = NULL;
        }
        return true;
    }
    QMessageBox::warning(this,QString("Error"),QString("Interface %1 doesn't exist or time is 0!").arg(interfaceLine->text()));
    return false;

}
```

I saw console print `command` first,but testBrowser isn't cleaned up.When popen() isfinished,testBrowser will be cleaned.Why?
How to make `clear()` work right now?Can i flush the textBrowser?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the internals of `QTextBrowser` but you might try calling [`qApp->processEvents()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) immediately after the call to `QTextBrowser::clear`.

Comment: QWidgets are not repainted immediately, instead it gathers all information together and paints in [paintEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#paintEvent). If the browser not seemed clear at the moment it is not a big deal. Important thing is result of [toPlainText()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#toPlainText). If it is true at any moment, then you are good to go.

Comment: Aside: You are already using Qt, why not use `QFile` to read your data? And `QString` to form your command?

Comment: @G.M. Perfect! it work for me,thanks!

Comment: @Caleth LGTM,i wil try,thanks.

Comment: @Kao i finally understand principle,thanks.